# Backbone collection reset and parse

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I am rendering a view in my backbone application when a collection is reset,

```
initialize: function(options) {
    this.options = options;

    this.model.get('projects').fetch({
        data: { 
            organisation_id: this.model.get('id')
        }
    }, {reset:true});

    this.model.get('projects').on('reset', this.render, this);
    this.model.get('projects').on('add', this.addNewProject, this);
    this.model.get('projects').on('sort', this.addProjects, this);
},

render: function() {

        console.log(this.model.get('projects').state);

        this.$el.html( this.template({
            is_owner: this.options.is_owner,
            className: this.options.className,
            pagination: this.model.get('projects').state
        }));

        this.addProjects();

        this.filter = new Pops.Views.OrganisationProjectsFilter({
            el:this.$el.find('.div-organisation-filter-wrapper'),
            model : this.model,
            collection: this.collection
        });

        this.filter.render().el;

        return this;
    },
```

As you can see I run a fetch and the reset my collection to the fetched data. My problem is that in the view I am trying to use some values that come from the server, and it appears they are null, here is my collection,

```
App.Collections.PaginatedProjects= 

Backbone.PageableCollection.extend({

        url: App.API_ROOT + "/projects/paginated",

        // Initial pagination states
        state: {
          pageSize: 2,
          sortKey: "name",
          order: 1,
          totalRecords:null
        },

        // You can remap the query parameters from `state` keys from
        // the default to those your server supports
        queryParams: {
          totalPages: null,
          totalRecords: null,
          sortKey: "sort",
        },

        // get the state from Github's search API result
        parseState: function (resp, queryParams, state, options) {
            this.state.totalRecords = resp.total;
            this.state.totalPages = resp.total / this.state.pageSize;
            this.state.lastPage = this.state.totalPages;
        },

        // get the actual records
        parseRecords: function (resp, options) {
          return resp.data;
        }
});
```

As you can see I am running the parse functions to retrieve and set to values, if I console my collection I can see the correct values, but when I try and use them in my view they are null, am I using parse or reset wrong or maybe both?

Comment: show the template & what templating engine are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because when you render the data didn't arrive yet. Try this:

```
this.model.get('projects').fetch({
    success: function(model,response) {
        var data = //some of your answer

    }   

});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you did a

```
console.log(this.model.get('projects').state);
```

and found out it is print out correctly but then used in the

```
this.template({
        is_owner: this.options.is_owner,
        className: this.options.className,
        pagination: this.model.get('projects').state
    })
```

then it does not appear? If this is the case, I don't think it's a problem in Backbone Collection. I think it has something to do with how you access the data in your template. 
If you are using handlebars, because this "state" variable is a json,

you maybe using

```
{{pagination.pageSize}}
```

in the hbs file to print it out. I have a heizy memory that it was not supported a while ago. try using

```
{{pagination/pageSize}}
```

Also, if this snippet is inside a {{#if}} or a {{#each}} etc, according to the handlebars documentation, you may need to go in a scope. use

```
{{../pagination/pageSize}} or {{../../pagination/pageSize}}
```

I ran into the problem a while ago and did a lot of search to found out about this. Hope it helps